# How async works understood correctly?

Tags: async-await

```
List<Results> stuff = DoSomeStuff();
await Task.run(SomeAsyncAction);
return stuff;
```

I have something similar to the above in my program. The task is supposed to update my database with results from an expensive calculation. Does this mean my async method would never execute the return statement until the awaitable has completed even though it already has what it needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, the method can't continue until the awaited asynchronous operation is complete.

Comment: I recommend reading up on asychronous programming with async and await here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent explanation here:
[https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/threads-events.pdf](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/threads-events.pdf)

async/await is an event-loop concurrency model.